# Solidus: sorting query with many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I am learning some Solidus (fork of Spree). I built the **sandbox** following the [readme](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus#sandbox)

Now i want to add a scope in Product to build a query that sorts products evaluating every variant. For each product i want to evaluate the lowest variant price of every product.

For instance, if i have three products

```
a.price = 2
b.price = 3
c.price = 4
```

a and b have only master variant, c has two variants

```
c.variants.first.price = 4
c.variants.last.price = 1
```

the ordered products should be

```
c, a, b
```

I managed to do this in the home#index working with arrays, but i broke the **cache(cache_key_for_products)** in **home/index.html.erb** method.

So i would like to do the same thing, but using **ActiveRecord_Relation**

I don't know how to build a good query with rails and solidus, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might be helpful for you.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord 
 has_many :variants,  dependent: :destroy
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :product
end


def index
 @products = Product.left_outer_joins(:variants).order("case when variants.id is null then products.price else variants.price end asc")
end
```